# pgAdmin 4 not starting on Windows 10 64bit

Tags: postgresql, startup, pgadmin

After a fresh install of postgres 9.6.0.1 for Windows 10 64bit I am not able to get pgAdmin 4 starting.

First it throws an fatal error message:

[image: message with fatal error when trying to launch pgAdmin 4]

After OK, that message appears:

[image: Configuration path of pgadmin]

Is there anything wrong? because after OK - the program won't start.

What can I do to get pgadmin 4 running? What should I enter in Python Path and what in Application Path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found now the problem, it was the Java installation on which pgadmin 4 depend heavily.

In Windows when installing Java 8 (Java SE in this case) you do not have to use JAVA_HOME and JAVA_JRE anylonger and you can install java with default path settings (with the version number)

So I installed JAVA SDK 8 32 and 64bit and pgadmin start up normally.
The PATH variable includes only C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath, thats all and let you use allways the latest version of java you installed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I installed pgAdmin 4 v4.25 (released Aug. 20, 2020) . It solved my issue .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I think, the installation of Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable is the source. 
I fixed it uninstalling pgAdmin 4 and installing it again.
It tried to install Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable again, but it was already installed and now it works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is really installing Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable, but unfortunatelly when reinstalling the whole DB and afterwards the pgadmin, same issue as described already. Anybody other ideas?

Comment: I have the same error on the same versions and it also persists after reinstalling (when de Redistributable package is already installed)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install pgamin 4.5.1, it works for me (w10 x64) [pgadmin 4.1.5](https://developer.pgadmin.org/~dpage/pgadmin4-1.5-x86.exe)

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for weeks with this problem I found a solution. In my case I have Anaconda installed and maybe it affects PgAdmin in some way, I don't know. In order to start PgAdmin  I followed these steps:

1. Open cmd and move to `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\web`
2. Run `pgAdmin4.py` with your Python distribution. I had to install several libraries.
3. In my case, an error appeared, I needed to change Line #32 of `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\browser\__init__.py`. More precisely:

`from flask_security.views import _security, _commit, default_render_json, _ctx`  to

`from flask_security.views import _security, _commit, _render_json, _ctx`

4. Last, I needed to edited line socket module from Python libraries, gethostbyaddr(name) found non-ASCII symbols in the host name of my computer, I don't have any of them :S. Well, I changed line #687

`hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)` to

`hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr("")`

5. After all of these steps I run pgAdmin4.py again and it worked.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me there was no way to make it work (pgAdmin4 Version 4.21 that comes with Postgres 11.8 on Windows 10 x64). I really tried every possible solution.

So I gave up and found pgAdmin3 Redux: https://tokavuh.com/pgAdmin3Redux/ that supports  Postgres 11, too.

You will probably have problems starting it, because of missing dll's from some Visual C++ Redistributable version I could not find out, but fortunately you will find these missing dll's on https://www.dll-files.com, just search them there as errors pops up.